# How to optimize this series of requests and iterations in python and mongodb

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have a `stock` collection of this form:

```
{
     _id: ObjectId("5e132f29009502d4e85e1293"),
     Product: ObjectId("5e132f29009502c4e97e8796"),
     Stock: [
         {
             Qty: 50, 
             Expiration Date: 2022-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
         }
     ]
}
```

This collection contains the current stock for each product. There are about 5000 entries.

Now I have to assess the stock on a given date. For this I use a simple formula:

```
stock = actual_stock + total_output - total_input
```

I have a collection for product inputs (arrival collection) and another for output operations (requisition collection):

**arrival collection**:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5e26eed55c0e07995d9f2cd0"),
    Order Number: 200049,
    Reception: [
        {Product: ObjectId(5e132f3e009502d4e85e2af4), Qty: 10, Expiration Date: 2022-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00}
    ],
    Date: 2020-01-21T13:30:13.529+00:00
}
```

**requisition collection**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5e26eed55c0e07995d9f2cd0"),
    Requisition Number: 200049,
    Products: [
        {Product: ObjectId(5e132f3e009502d4e85e2af4), Qty: 10, Expiration Date: 2022-05-01T00:00:00.000+00:00}
    ],
    Date: 2020-01-21T13:30:13.529+00:00
}
```

There is obviously other information in these documents, this is just an extract to show their composition.

Now here is the python code:

```
# imports ...
stock_db = mongo.db.Stock
arrival_db = mongo.db.Arrival
requisition_db = mongo.db.Requisitions


def check_arrival_product(product, date):
    check_arrival = arrival_db.aggregate([{'$unwind': '$Reception'},
                                          {'$match': {
                                              'Reception.Product': ObjectId(product),
                                              '$and': [
                                                  {'Reception.Date':
                                                      {'$gte': date}
                                                 }]}
                                           }])

    qty = 0
    for i in check_arrival:
        qty += i['Reception'].get('Qty')

    return qty


def check_requisition_product(product, date):
    check_requisition = requisition_db.aggregate([{'$unwind': '$Products'},                                         
                                                  {'$match': {
                                                      'Products.Product': ObjectId(product),
                                                      '$and': [
                                                          {'Date':
                                                              {'$gte': date}
                                                       }]}
                                                   }])

    qty = 0
    for i in check_requisition:
        qty += i['Products']['Qty']

    return qty


def main(date):
    # ....
    check_stock = stock_db.find()
    check_stock.batch_size(1000)
    for i in check_stock:
        stock = 0
        for j in i['Stock']:
            stock += j['Qty']

        total_arrival = check_arrival_product(i['Product'], date)
        total_requisition = check_requisition_product(i['Product'], date)

        stock = stock + total_requisition - total_arrival
    # ....
```

As you can see in the main function, I iterate on 5000 products and for each I have to evaluate the stock entered and taken out on a given date in order to calculate the stock on that date.

The major problem is that the operation takes up to 4 minutes, which is much too long.

P.S: The database is on the same computer.

So how can I optimize this kind of operation?

Comment: You may want include the collection data / fields which matches with your code - with field names and values need to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

My first idea would be to de-normalize the data. I.e: create a new collection e.g. 'transactions', and add an index on productId and date and add all transactions to it, both requisitions and arrivals. You can do that at runtime everytime a new transaction arrives, or as a batch job using two aggregation pipelines with a $out/$merge stage.

For the batch jobs, it should be something like this:

```
transaction_db.createIndex{
   "productId":1,
   "date":1
}
requisition_db.aggregate([
  {'$unwind': '$Products'},                                         
  //TODO: map productId, date, delta=-Qty
  {'$out': 'transaction_db'}                                               
])
arrival_db.aggregate([
  {'$unwind': '$Products'},                                         
  //TODO: map productId, date, delta=+Qty 
  {'$merge': {into: 'transaction_db'}}                                               
])
```

On this new collection, creating the inventory per productId would be a single aggregation pipeling using a $group stage.

```
transaction_db.aggregate([ { 
    $group: { 
        _id: {productId: "$productId", date: "$date"}, 
        deltaPerDay: { $sum: "$delta" }
    } 
} ] )
```

Another idea would be to take a look at the $lookup stage to join from products to  requisitions or arrivals. But for that you need to unwind them first to get individual product transaction, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Can you develop this idea a little more: **or as a batch job using two aggregation pipelines with a $out stage** ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 5000 products, you might be quicker if you keep them all in memory and calculate the delta's on the python side.

- First do a findAll for the current stock and keep all of them in a dictionary indexed by id.
- Then read all requisitions with findAll and update the stock in-memory.
- Then read all arrivals with findAll and update the stock in-memory.

If you have enough memory, this is a much easier implementation.